# <div> won't position properly in Chrome or Safari, but works perfectly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, safari, positioning

I'm redoing my site design at the moment I have a popout subscribe div at the side of the page. You can see my draft [here](http://freedomrequireswings-portal.blogspot.fr/):

It works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari it sticks out a bit.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id='Subscribe' style='z-index:10;position:fixed; top:376px; right:-231px; padding-left: 15px;display: inline-block;'>
<table background='http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gVytZ17cmL0/UAVf1PGc_tI/AAAAAAAABjM/rFNd4dqfwF4/s1600/background.PNG' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' id='side' style='border-left: 10px solid #565656; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #898989;' width='35px'>
<tbody>
<tr style='box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -3px #5E5E5E;'>
<td>
<font style='font-family:Lobster; color:#1bb4c6;font-size:18px;'>Subscribe</font><br/>
<form action='http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify' id='search-form1' method='post' onsubmit='window.open(&apos;http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=freedomrequireswings&apos;, &apos;popupwindow&apos;, &apos;scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520&apos;);return true' style='border:0px solid #ccc;text-align:left;margin-top:-20px;' target='popupwindow'>
<p>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input name='email' onblur='if(this.value==&apos;&apos;)this.value=this.defaultValue;' onfocus='if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=&apos;&apos;;' style='box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #121212; font-family:Segoe UI, Yanone Kaffeesatz, trebuchet MS;height:30px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;font-size:16px;color:#636363;' type='text' value='email@example.com' vinput=''/>
<input name='uri' type='hidden' value='FreedomRequiresWings'/>
<input name='loc' type='hidden' value='en_US'/>
</td>
<td>
<div style='padding-top:3px;'>
<input src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4zEgvyYwgH0/UAnajptLwxI/AAAAAAAABkw/lI_MFSWY1P8/s1600/sub%252B.png' style='height:49px !important; width:49px !important;' type='image'/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#Subscribe:hover {
transform: translate(-231px,0);
-ms-transform: translate(-231px,0);
-webkit-transform: translate(-231px,0);
-o-transform: translate(-231px,0);
-moz-transform: translate(-231px,0);
transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
position:fixed; 
display: inline-block;
}

#Subscribe {
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
display: inline-block;
}

#search-form1 input {
 width: 150px;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
#search-form1 input:focus {
 width: 250px;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

#search-form1 is the form for the email address to be put into. It's called search-form1 because I copied that particular code from a tutorial and I didn't change it. That works perfectly, all the functionalities are working, it's just that the div won't hide properly in Chrome or Safari. Haven't tried it on Opera. When I change the position:right property to -233px, it hides properly in Chrome and Safari, but it's in too far in Firefox.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this?

PS: If you have any criticism or suggestions for my site design draft, please let me know! I'd love to hear them.

[image: What happens in Firefox (Correct)]

[image: What happens with WebKit (Incorrect)]

Comment: This sounds like a webkit bug. If nobody else can find a problem with your code and it still occurs in the chrome and safari nightly builds, then you could file a bug here: https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: What happens if you add the following to your `table id="side"`: `position: relative; left: 2px;`

Comment: Just checked ... That breaks it in Firefox. Cross-browser fixing is a bear.

Comment: Nick: Yeah that breaks it in Firefox for me.

Comment: its good if you use div instead of tables as cellpadding is creating all this problem.

Comment: @SVS That didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try locking the width: 240px for #subscribe. (maybe not 240, but approx.)

Comment: Yes, this has fixed the problem, thank you. But now when you click to enter your email address, the bar expands off the screen. How could I do it so that #subscribe expands out to the left with it?

Comment: You'll have to add it to your event listener for the input to change the CSS position/size for the div again. Seems silly to change the size twice, though. Why not just bring it out farther the first time?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm new to CSS animation.

Comment: I would probably just pick ONE of these widths and then adjust #subscribe accordingly. `#search-form1 input { width: 150px; }
#search-form1 input:focus { width: 250px; }` (Either make them both 150 or 250.)